# Replace a string value in a column by values from same column in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, exists

I am working on table that has following 3 columns:

```
ID         ACCESS                RGN
_________________________________________
abc       NOT_RESTRICTED        NOT_RESTRICTED
def          1                  W
ghi          MK                 SW
jkl          3001               N
```

I want to select values from RGN for a particular ID. When NOT_RESTRICTED, should return all other values in the RGN column from another table and will have similar values like W,SW and N else should return the corresponding value for a specific ID.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *When NOT_RESTRICTED, should return all other values in the RGN column from another table*: what other table? You are just showing one table. Please extend your sample data and let us see your expected results too.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and the schema of "another table" would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to join two tables conditionally as following:

```
Select t1.id, t1.access. t2 rgn
  From table t1 join table t2
    On t1.rgn = t2.rgn  Or t1.rgn = 'NOT_RESTRICTED'
```

This will do cross join when the `rgn` is `NOT_RESTRICTED` else give specific rgn.

Cheers!!